# How can I display a number from a report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

I'm trying to display a number which is generated each time on a report and have it displayed each time it's updated into a Form page

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to reports like you do with forms. There is a Reports-Collection, like the Forms-Collection and a report has a Controls-Collection like a form.

```vb
Reports.Item("MyReportName").Controls.Item("ControlNameOnReport")
```

or the short bang version:

```vb
Reports!MyReportName!ControlNameOnReport
```

But you should extract the generation of the value to a public function and call that function if necessary.